# Angular Select Box Option padding issue Google Chrome?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am having in issue within chrome regarding a select box dropdown being populated with Angular. Within google chrome there seems to be a padding issue (see link with image below). This padding issue does not occur on any other browsers and I do not see the issue when being displayed with laptop resolution on chrome. I wonder if anyone else has come across this issue and has a solution? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you possibly show us some of your code? Any related HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: @Lamp It turned out to be an issue with the select box being within an iframe in chrome.

Comment: @mhauber92 Are you able to elaborate further? I have the same issue, reproducible on a colleagues computer, but not mine.